# Accumulate Array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum

I have the following code snipped which works but is incredibly slow:

```
bps = [5; 10; 15; 20]
src = ['10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2'; '10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2']

uniqueSrc = unique(src);

sumBps = [];
for i=1:length(uniqueSrc)
    indy=find(ismember(src,uniqueSrc(i)));
    sumBps = [sumBps; sum(bps(indy))];
end

uniqueSrc = ['10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2']
sumBps = [20; 30]
```

src is a cell array containing IP adresses while one IP can occur multiple times. It is read from a file with textscan and %s. bps contains integers.

I need to sum up all integers in bps that belong to the same IP adress in src.
The matching is according to the indices. So src(1) is the IP of bps(1) and so on.

The result should be a matching of the IPs to the sum of the corresponding bps values. So uniqueSrc(1) is the IP that has a sumBps(1) that is the sum of all bps values belonging to the certain IP.

While my code certainly works it is very unefficient as it seems and i wonder what would be the famous matlab one-liner to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added example input and output.

Comment: Post a small example input and the desired output

Comment: The input would be nice. How are you storing your IP addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic use of [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
%// Your inputs
bps = [5; 10; 15; 20];
src = ['10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2'; '10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2'];

%// Relevant code
[uniqueSrc,~,id] = unique(cellstr(src));
sumBps = accumarray(id, bps);
```

---

The above code probably deserves some explanation.  `accumarray` is a function that bins or groups data together based on IDs.  As such, what I did was I converted `src` to a cell array with [`cellstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html), then used [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get a list of all of the unique IP addresses in addition to assigning a unique ID to each IP address.  The unique IP addresses are stored in `uniqueSrc` which is the first output of `unique` and each IP address in `src` is assigned a unique ID stored in `id`.  An intricacy that not many people think about is that `unique` not only finds unique entries in an array, but it also returns those values **sorted**.  From this sorted result, the IDs assigned to each element in `src` would follow this ordering convention.  Because you want to return those IP addresses in order (it looks like it), then we don't need to think about this part.  Also, I needed to convert your IP addresses into a cell array for this to work.

Once we determine these, we use `accumarray` where the first element is an ID for each IP address and the second element is what value each IP address maps to.  By default, `accumarray` bins those values that share the same ID and **sums** them all up.  That pretty much describes what exactly it is you want to do.

The output I get for your desired variables is:

```
>> uniqueSrc

uniqueSrc = 

    '10.0.0.1'
    '10.0.0.2'

>> sumBps

sumBps =

    20
    30
```

Comment: @eigenchris - I'm not sure if my edit came before or after your comment lol.

Comment: I'm not either, haha.  I deleted it either way. Good answer, though.

Comment: The title kinda gives it away :-) . Almost posted but was looking to catenate the addresses and summed bps values into rows.

Comment: I was typing exactly the same answer, except I wrote "usual" instead of "classic". I like your term better ;-)

Comment: @TryHard  - Oh! That's a good idea!  If you have MATLAB R2013b or higher, try displaying them in a `table`.

Comment: @LuisMendo - lol thank you :)  I saw "accumulate array" and I couldn't help but answer it.  `accumarray` is probably my favourite function to date.  `bsxfun` is a close second (Divakar would be proud).

Comment: @rayryeng Proud... or jealous? :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo - LOL.  That depends on his mood :D.

Answer (score 1):

Add my answer because I wanted to show how to catenate the IP addresses and summed bps, plus you don't need to convert to cell if you use the option `rows` with `unique`:

```
bps = [5; 10; 15; 20]
src = ['10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2'; '10.0.0.1'; '10.0.0.2'];

[strng ii jj]= unique(src,'rows');


strcat( {strng},{char(32)*ones(size(strng,1),1)},{num2str(accumarray(jj,bps))})
```

Comment: OH! Good job with the 'rows' flag!

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah but generally speaking its better to work with cell arrays unless your strings are always equal in length, which isn't a guarantee.

Comment: Yup that's why I decided to go with cells.  This is certainly a toy case, but I would certainly stick with cells for variable length strings.  Good going!